# How to get the same reference given same arguments for equality test

Tags: javascript, typescript

I build a map given tuples of string and number.
I want to cache this map, so when I want to create another map with the same given tuples, I get the same map. How can I do this?

```
export type Board = Map<string, number>

let boards: Array<Board> = []

function makeBoard(res: Array<[string, number]>): Board {
    let b = new Map();
    res.forEach(([str, num]) => {
        b.set(str, num);
    });
    return b;
}

let a1 = ['hello', 1]
let a2 = ['world', 2]


let b1 = makeBoard([a1, a2]);
let b2 = makeBoard(([a1, a2]));
let b3 = makeBoard((([a2, a1])));
let b4 = makeBoard(([a1]));

console.log('I want both to be true');
console.log(b1 === b2, b2 === b3);
console.log('I want this to be false');
console.log(b1 === b4);
```

I think I should hash the values, and put it in a map, then check the value of the map to match given input if it already exists return otherwise create a new result and put it in the map. I want this to be generic.

I thought this approach would make things easier for equality testing but maybe it's not necessary?

Comment: Do you use the maps for any other purpose?

Comment: No I don't mutate the map ever again. Just for lookups.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I should hash the values, and put it in a map, then check the value of the map to match given input if it already exists return otherwise create a new result and put it in the map.

Yes, that is what I would suggest. You can first sort the array you get, and then stringify it (e.g. as JSON), and use that as key in a map of maps:

Note that in your existing code, you can use the Map constructor to build the map from those pairs in one go.

```js
let superMap = new Map;

function makeBoard(res) {
    res.sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) || a - b);
    let key = JSON.stringify(res);
    let b = superMap.get(key);
    if (b === undefined) {
        b = new Map(res);
        superMap.set(key, b);
    }
    return b;
}

let b1 = makeBoard([["hello", 1], ["world", 2]]);
let b2 = makeBoard([["hello", 1], ["world", 2]]);
let b3 = makeBoard([["world", 2], ["hello", 1]]);
let b4 = makeBoard([["hello", 1]]);

console.log('I want both to be true');
console.log(b1 === b2, b2 === b3);
console.log('I want this to be false');
console.log(b1 === b4);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that possible pairs are reference equal to each other would that help in a way to use a different approach?

Comment: Yes, then you could create yet another Map to map those pairs to unique integers (incremental). The more you know about the data, the better solution you can make. If for instance those strings are within a closed set, maybe a coordinate, then you could map those to a range of integers... If these ranges are limited, then you could use bitmaps... It all depends on your real data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some kind of cache with a hash of the arguments. something like this: (didn't test the code)

```
let boards: Array<Board> = []
const cache: {[args:string]:Board}= {};
function makeBoard(res: Array<[string, number]>): Board {
    const hash = JSON.stringify(res.sort((a:[string,number],b:[string,number])=>(a[0]+a[1] > b[0]+b[1])?1:-1));
    if (cache[hash]!==undefined)
    return cache[hash]
    let b = new Map();
    res.forEach(([str, num]) => {
        b.set(str, num);
    });
    return b;
}
```